# R script SRTM DEM

Tags: qgis, r, srtm

Someone who has experience with R in Qgis can help me with this problem.
I have a script that works perfectly in R making downloads SRTM DEM and cuts to the desired polygon.
But I can't implement it in qgis.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(elevatr)
library(viridis)
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
setwd("D:/teste_MDT/1")
pol_mask <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/teste_MDT/1", layer = "2")
#crs(pol_mask) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
plot(pol_mask)
dem <- get_elev_raster(pol_mask, z = 11, override_size_check = TRUE)
plot(dem)
writeRaster(dem, filename= "dem.tif")
crop_dem <- mask(x= crop(dem, pol_mask), pol_mask, filename = "crop.tif")
plot(crop_dem)
```

[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be running an old version of `elevatr` that doesn't work with `sf` objects.

QGIS' R scripts get passed vector data as `sf` objects, but the error looks like it is trying to run `sp` functions (`spTransform` is mentioned) on an `sf` object.

Try updating `elevatr`, or converting the vector layer to an `sp` object with something like:

`pol_mask_sp = as(pol_mask,"Spatial")`

and working with that.

Comment: I implemented the following changes but I keep getting the same message.

DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. Comes from another installation of PROJ.
Error in h (simpleError (msg, call)):
error evaluating 'CRSobj' argument in method selection for 'spTransform' function: 'NA'
Calls: get_elev_raster -> estimate_raster_size -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution interrupted

Comment: I would suspect there is a mismatch in package versions used by R standalone and those executed from QGIS rprocessing plugin. Make sure the R Processing Options: User library folder points out to your local R library rather QGIS profile folder.